# JPA annotation @DiscriminatorValue on root entity does not return expected results or returns all records

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, annotations

I have following entities:

```
@Table(name="Animal")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("Animal")
public class Animal{
// code brevity
}

@Entity
@Discriminatorvalue("Dog")
public class Dog extends Animal{
// code brevity
}
```

So when I run the jpa query *entityManager.createQuery("from Animal").getResultList()*, it returns me all the records in Animal table **where DTYPE in ('Animal', 'Dog')** instead of **where DTYPE in('Animal')**. How can I get records returned **where DYTPE = 'Animal'** only?

Comment: show the code you are using to fetch the results.

Comment: @dassum I already mentioned this in question that I am using entityManager.createQuery("from Animal").getResultList() to fetch the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter *from Animal* means instances of type Animal. Any instance of type *Dog* is also an instance of type *Animal* and will be also selected. This works correct. And if you later on have more subclasses and select *from Animal*, you again will get *all* instances including subclasses.

If you want to exclude instances of type *Dog*, you should do that *explicitly* in your query.

I'd suggest that you change your model and don't use any discriminator for the base class. Thus you will avoid such incorrect expectations: No developer in your team will expect that selection *from Animal* will select only part of the records; everyone will understand that select will return *all* entities of *all* subclasses. Use discriminator values for subclasses only.

Comment: so if I change the model, then I would  not like anyone in my team to insert/update/select Animal only. so do you suggest, I make the class Animal as abstract and create another subclass GenericAnimal (subclass of Animal) parallel to Dog ?

Comment: You can insert and update even now. But in the select you have to explicitly exclude other subclasses, which will make queries too complex. Yes, it would be better to create another subclass. But I'd suggest to consider other name. GenericAnimal sounds similar to just Animal and one can expect that it is a base class of Dog. Name like UndefinedAnimal or OtherAnimal would better because the chance to misunderstand its meaning is less.